# mobile number validation pattern that accepts only 6,7,8,9 as first digit and allows only 0-9 as input

Tags: validation

I want a pattern that allows only 0-9 numbers as input and should allow only 6,7,8,9 as first digit

```
patt = /^([0-9])$/;
```

this is what I've tried but it doesn't validate the first digit to be 6789

Comment: What you currently have, would only allow for a single digit, because you did not include any quantifier. Just put a class that contains of only 1-9 first, no quantifier, and then your 0-9 class _with_ quantifiert.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern,

`var pattern = /^[6,7,8,9][0-9]{0,9}$/;`